# Interview email follow-up (Web Developer role)

Tags: human-resources, websites, web

I recently went for an interview with a new startup company for a *Web Developer role*.

The interview was with the project manager, and it went quite well and it lasted about 45 mins and I'm able to answer most of his question, he also shared more about the company, the team he is recruiting, job description, clients the company is managing, the company's rival in the current market.

He did mention that he is currently interviewing other candidates too, and he asked me whether I am too.

Lastly he did mention to me that **" Sent me an email in a week, for a follow-up and to stay in touch with him, and he did told me to go for other interview as well "**.

So what should i email him back? Asking him whether the job is still open ? or...Please help..??? =(

FYI..(I did email him (***a thank you email***) within 24hrs after the interview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send a follow up email as requested.

> Hi xxx.  As requested, I'm sending you a follow up email.  Thanks again for the interview last week - I'm still very interested in working with you if the position is still available.
>
> Thanks, blah blah blah.

And see what the response is from that.  You may wish to include any information that didn't get covered in the interview or that you chose not to go ahead with the other jobs.